# Can we erase the items in range-based for loop in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to erase all the items less than `v` in C++11 standard container `set`, here is my code:

```
void delete_less_than(set<int> & ss, int const v) {
   for (auto item: ss) {
      if (item < v) {
        ss.erase(ss.find(item));
      } else break;
  }  
}
```

Will the code work properly? I seems okay on my computer (g++ 4.7.3), but loops infinitely on some online judge where I submit my code.

Comment: Even i love the range for, a good example that convince might be no good (assume some function calls something modifying the container).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That's not what the range-based loop is for. Don't use it; use a normal `for` loop instead. The range-based version is only if you want to do something with every element in the container, *without mutating the container*.

```
for (auto it = ss.begin(); it != ss.end(); )
{
    if (*it < v) { ss.erase(it++); }
    else         { ++it;           }
}
```

Even simpler:

```
ss.erase(ss.begin(), ss.lower_bound(v));
```

Comment: thx, I also want to whether the behavior the my code is defined or not?  Or does it dependent on the compiler?

Comment: @notbad: it's undefined. The standard defines the code which a range-based for is equivalent to. That code uses an iterator, and the iterator it uses is invalidated by the `erase`.

Comment: @notbad: What Steve said. Check 6.5.4 for the definition of the operational semantics of the range-based loop; you end up using invalid iterators with your code.

Comment: Surely `lower_bound`, we're deleting stuff less than `v` but not `v` itself if present.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thanks - I was intent on deleting `v` for some reason...

Comment: Oh, that `lower_bound` solution is sexy!

Comment: @FredOverflow: Why not use the efficient algorithms that your data structure affords :-)

Comment: I've worried whether `ss.erase(it++);` invalidates the `it` iterator.  Is it okay, since `it` is incremented by the side-effect of `it++` _before_ `ss.erase()` is invoked, and hence the post-increment `++` is still operating on a valid iterator (and since iterators to non-erased elements are still valid after std::set::erase())?  So, would swapping in two statements, `ss.erase(it); ++it;` then be using an invalid iterator?  Could relying on a fine distinction like this be an issue for clarity or maintainability?

Comment: @anthrond: `erase(it++)` is fine; `erase(it); ++it;` is not fine, because `erase` invalidates the iterator.

Comment: But doesn't the `std::lower_bound`-solution need a sorted range?

Comment: @ChristianRau: It's your lucky day: `std::set<int>` *is* already sorted :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Hah right, I totally missed that. I think I just read a question about `std::string` right before and must have messed that up.

Comment: `ss.erase(it++);` is clever but relying on pre-/post-increment semantics is setting up future maintainers for trouble.  `erase` returns the next iterator, so the usual recommended solution is `it = ss.erase(it);`