# Removing one element of a vector while in a loop

Tags: c++

```
for (Shape *i : shapes) {
    for (Shape *j : shapes) {
        if (i != j) {
            if (check(i,j)){
                shapes.erase(remove(shapes.begin(), shapes.end(), i), shapes.end());
```

this causes an error because it's going to carry on iterating even though i does not exist, my question is how do I cleanly do this? currently I get an error "vector iterator not incrementable"

Can i just exit the second loop and continue in the first one?

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597240/how-to-delete-an-element-from-a-vector-while-looping-over-it

Comment: [range-based-for + sequence modification = bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317068/can-we-erase-the-items-in-range-based-for-loop-in-c11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the positioning of your `shapes` elements while using ranged-based `for` loops.  The range loop uses iterators internally, and erasing `vector` elements invalidates existing iterators.

Try something more like this instead:

```
auto iter = shapes.begin();
auto end = shapes.end();
while (iter != end) {
    auto iter2 = shapes.begin();
    bool erased = false;
    while (iter2 != end) {
        if ((iter != iter2) && check(*iter, *iter2)) {
            iter = shapes.erase(iter); 
            end = shapes.end(); 
            erased = true;
            break;
        }
        ++iter2;
    }
    if (!erased)
        ++iter;
}
```

Alternatively, maybe something more like this would also work:

```
shapes.erase(
  std::remove_if(shapes.begin(), shapes.end(),
    [shapes&](Shape *i) {
        for (Shape *j : shapes) {
            if ((i != j) && check(i, j)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
  ),
  shapes.end()
);
```

Comment: Could I also do iter2 = shapes.erase(iter2) below the first erase?

Comment: You are only operating on one `vector`, so you have to be very careful with how you manage the iterators. Doing a second `erase` will affect the new iterators obtain from the first `erase`. Do you really want to remove multiple elements per loop iteration?

Comment: yeah once two objects return true after the check they both need to be removed

Comment: That gets a bit trickier to manage when using iterators. You might have to switch to indexes instead. It would help to know what `check()` is actually checking, and whether `j` can ever be before `i` in the check result, or will `j` always be after `i`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot erase elements from a vector when you are iterating it by for range loop, as internally it uses iterators that would be invalidated. This should work:

```
auto end = shapes.end();
for( auto it = shapes.begin(); it != end; ++it ) {
    end = shapes.erase( std::remove_if( std::next( it ), shapes.end(), [it]( Shape *s ) { 
             return check( *it, s ); 
         }, shapes.end() );
}
```

Note this code is slightly more effective than yours but it assumes that `check( s1, s2 ) == check( s2, s1 )`, if you can change your `check()` function to do strict ordering comparison, rather than equivalence, then you would be able to use `std::sort` and `std::unique` which are even more effective.

Comment: is there a way to remove both "it" and "s"?

Comment: @user1234 I do not quite understand the question

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a range-for loop in this case. Instead use a standard loop with iterators:

for (auto iter = shapes.begin(); iter != shapes.end(); iter++)